# How to add dynamic variables in data target for django

Tags: django, bootstrap-modal

```
{% for key,value in config.items %}
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target='#'{{key}}><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
 <div class="modal fade" id={{ key}} role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">{{key}}</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>    
{% endfor %}
```

//I want to call each element by {{key}} so that I can display all the values based on the loop value.Please anyone suggest me how to fix this issue

Comment: What is the _issue_?

Comment: as i am looping in through the dictonary I want to have that dictonary value in the modal each time we try to access the  modal.But the problem is i am not able to get it

Comment: "I am not able to get it" is not a problem description. Please post what is your target and what you get instead.

Comment: " ** id={{ key}}**" why this and clear your requirement

Comment: I have a datatable where the rows are getting displayed based on the loop value.Now in one of the coulumn i want to have a modal which displays the row value.Can u guide @seluck

Comment: can anyone help into here